# Не отсылаются данные на сервер

Tags: javascript, node.js, greasemonkey

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,  Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World!')
});


app.get('/href', function(req, res){
   res.send('Hello World! href')
});

app.post('/href', function(req, res){
   var obj = {};
   console.log('body: ' + req.body);
   //res.send(req.body);
   res.send(req.body);
});
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port

console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
```

link.js

```
 // ==UserScript==
// @name        videos_user_open
// @namespace   my_01
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/channel/*
// @include     http://localhost:8081/href
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('hello this videos script');
  var videos;
  var linksArray = [
  ];
  var href = 'http://localhost:8081/href';
  var dataLink = {
  };
  var just = {
    fName1: 'value1',
    fName2: 'http://localhost:8081/href',
    fName3: href
  };
  $('ul h3.yt-lockup-title').find('a').slice(0, 2).each(function (i, e) {
    videos = 'http://www.youtube.com' + $(e).attr('href');
    linksArray.push(videos);
    dataLink['link' + i] = videos;
    console.log(videos);

  });
  console.log(linksArray);
  console.log('this is data___', dataLink);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataLink),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: href,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: как я понял ошибка заключается в асинхронности. dataLink еще не сформировался а уже был отправлен методом POST? Если поставить переменную just вместо dataLink, то все работает...

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны подождать момента,когда dataLink сформируется.Это можно сделать тремя способами:

1. использовать callback
2. использовать promise
3. использовать генераторы для control flow

P.S. Маленький совет, забудьте о существовании JQuery. Все можно сделать на чистом JS и код будет чище и понятнее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ я уже сам разобрался